# How to get user's google market account?

Tags: android

How can I get the user's market account, the account with which they install applications in google market, from code?

Comment: you mean the email id which the device is configured to?

Comment: yes, the enail with which the user signs in to android market

Comment: Could you get answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were looking for Configured Email Id of the device, this will help you.

```
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(ContactUs.this).getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
      // TODO: Check possibleEmail against an email regex or treat
      // account.name as an email address only for certain account.type values.
      String possibleEmail = account.name;
     Log.i("Email ID",possibleEmail);

    }
```

Comment: This answer does not return the gmail account used to sign-in Android Market rather gives all the accounts set-up on a device.This is not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yet better you try to get only the google account(s) like this:

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");
for (Account account : accounts) {
 // this is where the email should be in: 
  String email = account.name;
}
```

Comment: I used this approach and for certain users I got null - Is that possible?
Also, can this return non gmail accounts if using getAccountsByType("com.google")? I saw that I get some other accounts types...

Comment: This answer does not return the gmail account used to sign-in Android Market rather gives all the accounts set-up on a device.This is not the answer to the question.